# Laravel 4 and jQuery Select2: Old Input

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-4, jquery-select2

I'm trying to pass old input to a select2 component, but select2 doesn't pick it up.

(Note: I'm using TwigBridge)

```
<select ... value="{{ input_old('fiscal_year_span') }}">
    ... options ...
</select>
```

The options do have set value names, and Laravel does send the old value back.

(I hope I don't need to do this with JS...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're adding a `value` param to the select tag, vs a `selected` param to an option tag.

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad. (I do that every now and then - thanks for reminding me).

Comment: You and me both. Glad you got it figured out!

Comment: But how do you make it display a selected to param when it's going to return the value of the selected option :x

Comment: @RainbowHat You can set a third parameter in `Form::select()` if you want an option to be selected. ex `{{ Form::select('nameOfSelect', array('S' => 'Small', 'M' => 'Medium', 'L' => 'Large'), 'M') }}` the "Medium" option will be selected.